# Moving a directory tree with only some of the files

Tags: bash, unix, cp

I have files structured as follows:

```
folder1
-file1.a
-file2.b
-file3.c
folder2
-file1.a
-file2.b
folder3
-file1.a
-file2.b
-file3.c
```

I want to copy just the files with .a and preserving the tree structure:

```
folder1
-file1.a
folder2
-file2.a
folder3
-file3.a
```

How can I accomplish this using bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have GNU `cp` (linux) you can:

```
cp --parent folder*/**/*.a /path/to/destination
```

or with two piped `tar`

```
tar czf - folder*/**/*.a | tar -C /path/to/dest -xvf -
```

or

```
find folder* -name \*.a -print | cpio -o | (cd /path/to/dest ; cpio -idv)
```

or better, from the @JonathanLeffler's comment

```
find folder* -name '*.a' -print | cpio -pvd /path/to/dest
#and with null terminated
find ... -print0 | cpio -p0dv /path/to/dest
```

The `**` mean (from man bash)

> - Matches  any string, including the null string.  When the globstar shell option is enabled, and *
>                      is used in a pathname expansion context, two adjacent *s used as a single pattern will match  all
>                      files  and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If followed by a /, two adjacent *s will
>                      match only directories and subdirectories.

the `globstar` (default on)

> **globstar**
>                         If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all  files  and  zero  or
>                         more  directories  and  subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and
>                         subdirectories match.

Comment: What are the double asterisks for?

Comment: I was almost going to upvote for using `cpio`, but you've forgotten about the `-p` option: `find folder* -name '*.a' -print | cpio -pvd /path/to/dest`.  _[…a little time passes…]_ You've got my up-vote now you've fixed it.  (And, FWIW, Mac `cpio` has a `-0` option to handle lists of names terminated by null bytes; GNU `cpio` likely does too, so `find … -print0 | cpio -p0dv /path/to/dest` would work well too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler YES! Youre right! ;) :) Edited - added!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a tar file with files you need...and then extract that tar where ever you want it...eg. below

```
$ tar -cvf allfiles.tar `find . -name "*.a" -print`
$ cp allfiles.tar /newdirectory
$ cd /newdirectory
$ tar -xvf allfiles.tar
```

Another Way would be ...

```
# below command will find all files with .a extension and then 
# copy them to the newdir directory with folder structure.
$ cp --parents `find . -name "*.a" -print` newdir
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop:

```
for f in folder{1..3}; do mkdir -p "dest/$f" && cp "src/$f/file1.a" "dest/$f"; done
```

For example:

```
$ ls src/* 
src/folder1:
file1.a  file2.b  file3.c

src/folder2:
file1.a  file2.b  file3.c

src/folder3:
file1.a  file2.b  file3.c
$ for f in folder{1..3}; do mkdir -p "dest/$f" && cp "src/$f/file1.a" "dest/$f"; done
$ ls dest/*
dest/folder1:
file1.a

dest/folder2:
file1.a

dest/folder3:
file1.a
```